# AEB on the Canon Rebel T2i

Tags: canon, raw, exposure, canon-550d, hdr

Hi I'm new to this whole HDR scene and I actually have a few questions regarding this.   I was trying to take RAW photos with my camera set to AEB on -2, 0, and +2 exposure today with continuous shot enabled on AV mode.  When I got home and uploaded the files onto my computer, I was expecting to see 3 photos per shot for each of the 3 exposure levels.  But to my dismay I only saw one RAW photo per shot and it's either at +2 or -2 exposure, which was super disheartening.

How would you set your Canon T2i up so that it takes up to 3 photos per shot per exposure please?  I thought continuous shot setting would take care of this, but.. I guess not?

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably only pressed long enough to get one shot. In order to get all three shots you have to keep the shutter-release pressed long enough. This is the most common behavior although very few cameras can take all shots after a single press. In any case, given this is a DSLR, you should be able to hear the shots as they are taken.

Keep in mind that if you are shooting in lowish light, you may have to keep the shutter pressed for long, particularly since the +2 EV shot takes 4 times as long as the baseline shot.

In single-shot drive, you press once per exposure until all three images in the bracket are done. This is often better as you can time each shot around objects entering and exiting the scene.

Comment: Ooohhhh thank you!  I just tried it and it was cause I didn't press it long enough as you suggested.  

So for the single-shot drive, would you have to manually adjust the exposure as well or will the bracket automatically skip to the next exposure after a shot is done with?

Comment: @FloK - Yes. Each time you shoot, the next exposure will be taken and which one is indicated in the viewfinder status line.

Comment: I've always wished for a setting on Canons that allowed the user to take all three shots without cycling the mirror when then mirror is locked up.

Answer (score 2):

I've shot AEB with a Canon 40D, 7D, and 5D2. They all do this. Itai is right, you are only pressing the shutter button once.

However, on all three bodies above and hopefully on your T2i, set the auto-timer, 2 seconds is good enough. That makes the camera shoot all 3 exposures.

Comment: If you have the mirror locked up and use the auto-timer, does the camera take all three exposures without cycling the mirror?

Comment: Nope! The mirror goes up and down, gotta love it... :- ( I've been using MagicLantern on the 5D which has more mirror lockup options but I've not figured it out yet.

Comment: Thanks!  I shall give that auto timer a shot!  I guess that would minimize any potential shaking even with a tripod set up!

Comment: Oh by the way, is there a way so that you don't have to set up the AEB every time you turn on the camera please?  Cause I have noticed that the AEB resets every time you turn on/off the camera, but it gets annoying to have to go into menu to set it to the desired exposure bracket each and every single time.